# Code snippet error display

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I am glad to use the StackCodeSnippet on the site. Just a few question aroses in me.

Should a snippet like this display error messages, as my Browser debugger (as in the one pressing F12) does?
I should then add it manually. It would be a great help for those watching my question, if it could be debuggeable on site!

What about some changes like these?

Comment: Not sure what you ask. What error messages exactly? What browser debugger, and where you want to see them?